# Change one part of the selection with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to insert a class with regex and preg_replace

```
echo preg_replace("/<li\>\s*<p\>[a-z]\)\s/", "/<li class=\"inciso\"\>\s*<p\>[a-z]\)\s/", $documento);
```

This is the model of text that I haveEste é o modelo das linhas do meu documento:

```
<li>
  <p>a) long text</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>b) long text</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>c) long text</p>
</li>
```

New example, let´s say that is not a HTML, is just a simple list, and you wanna a change from this:

```
a) long text
b) long text
c) long text
```

To this:

```
a) new text long text
b) new text long text
c) new text long text

echo preg_replace("/[a-z]\)\s/", "/[a-z]\)\snew\stext/", $documento);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: It depends. If you don't have to **parse** it, it's fine and maybe easier. It depends on the task and on the document you have.

Comment: I edit the question, at the end to make it clear

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Few questions about the part you added: you are replacing "every word followed by a space. Is that what you want? Or do you need to replace just the word "long"?

Comment: Yes, it has a space, and the word "long", is just a sample, the content changes from this part. The only part that stay stable is the beginning to the space after the ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `str_replace` instead.

```
$find    = '<li>';
$replace = '<li class="inciso">';


echo str_replace($documento, $find, $replace);
```

Comment: But I have others instance of <li>, that don´t matches what I want.

Comment: than describe better what you want. (the exact strings). In general you should not use regexp for that.

Comment: Sorry Lisa. ;) . But if I can´t use regex, what are my option?

Comment: If you have a way to uniquely identify in one go all the `<li>` you need (like if they are always followed by a character, or if they have specific attributes and so on...) to replace then you can use regexes, otherwise no

Comment: @AlêMoraes try using a html parser , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php ( see part about Simple HTML Dom Parser ). regexp gets too complicated and you'll run into issues where your string does not match ( for example characters like ẽ)

Answer (score 1):

**IF**, and I emphasize again **IF**, the input text you have is like the one you posted here, **then you can assume** you can find a safe pattern to replce, as you won't see this pattern somewhere else:

```
preg_replace("/<li>/", "<li class=\"inciso\"\/>", $documento);
```

This will replace *every* occurrence of `<li>` with the modified version. If there are `<li>` that you won't replace then it becomes more difficult and you should use a DOM or SAX parser

**UPDATE after your update:** You can match a word and add something before it with:

```
preg_replace("(long)", "new text $1", $documento);
```

Have a look at [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)